# Checking Items in a CheckedBoxList based on Database Data

Tags: c#

I have a CheckedListBox in my c# application that displays the existing items in the database. Now, for each supplier I want to check the items it supplies. Following is what I have done so far.

```
string sel_supplied = "SELECT * FROM item_supplier WHERE supplier_id='" + hid_supid.Text + "'";
MySqlCommand cmd_supplied = new MySqlCommand(sel_supplied, Class_Connection.conn);

try
{
    MySqlDataReader rdr_supplied = cmd_supplied.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr_supplied.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item: " + rdr_supplied["item_id"]);
        int i=0;

        foreach (DataRowView row in chklist_items.Items)
        {                            
            //MessageBox.Show(row[chklist_items.ValueMember].ToString());
            if (row[chklist_items.ValueMember].ToString() == rdr_supplied["item_id"].ToString())
            {
                chklist_items.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
            i++;
        }                        
    }
    rdr_supplied.Close();
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But the code generating an exception saying that, the list is being changed (as being checked runtime) and enumerator cannot be used for changing list.

Any help is appreciated, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change the collection on which you are iterating through `foreach` loop which is not allowed, you can use `for` loop instead.

```
for(int i=0;i < chklist_items.Items.Count; i++)
{                            
    //MessageBox.Show(row[chklist_items.ValueMember].ToString());
    DataRowView row =  (DataRowView)chklist_items[i];
    if (row[chklist_items.ValueMember].ToString() == rdr_supplied["item_id"].ToString())
    {
        chklist_items.SetItemChecked(i, true);
    }     
 }
```

Comment: I once had this in my mind. But can you tell me how could I get the datarow in that case?

Comment: chklist_items.Items[i] will give you the row

Comment: The problem is, I need to access the value member of the items. Is there any other way you can suggest to get around this problem?

Comment: The error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to System.Data.DataRowView"...

Comment: You have to check the type of object which you bind on CheckBoxList. If it is DataRowView then you can cast it like DataRowView row = (DataRowView )chklist_items[i];

Comment: Now this works absolutely fine. Thank you so much @Adil. Hats off to you.